# Why all the mail that is sent from my web app is being marked as spam?

Tags: gmail, sendmail, spam, spf

I'm the developer for the site http://crowdculture.eu, and all the mail that comes from the server the app is set on is marked as spam. I am using sendmail to send emails from server.

- I have checked and neither the domain or my server IP is in the any sort of blacklist
- I have gone through and configured a spf(Sender Policy Framework) for the domain to recognize my servers IP as the original sender. (v=spf1 ip4:69.194.224.168/16 ~all) I've tested it with available tools online and it says that SPF works fine - http://www.openspf.org/Why?id=user%40crowdculture.eu&ip=69.194.224.168&receiver=tools.bevhost.com:%2069.194.224.168/16
  Still test says that my emails are rejected: "The domain crowdculture.eu has authorized 69.194.224.168 to send mail on its behalf, so the message should have been accepted. It is impossible for us to say why it was rejected."

Is there any way that Gmail can reveal to me why is all the mail still marked as spam so that at least I have some direction on what to try next?

For some reason reverse DNS does not work for my server IP the domain configuration is stored in different place could it be because of the rDNS? Now I'm waiting to get access to configure rDNS but this is shot in the dark for me it would be much easier for me to know exact reason.

here is the raw spam mail:

```
Delivered-To: janis.kesteris3@gmail.com
Received: by 10.236.24.231 with SMTP id x67csp74923yhx;
        Wed, 6 Jun 2012 02:20:14 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.68.130.9 with SMTP id oa9mr57938587pbb.95.1338974413769;
        Wed, 06 Jun 2012 02:20:13 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <user@crowdculture.eu>
Received: from crowdculture.eu ([69.194.224.168])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id qn6si1844885pbc.225.2012.06.06.02.20.13
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Wed, 06 Jun 2012 02:20:13 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@crowdculture.eu designates 69.194.224.168 as permitted sender) client-ip=69.194.224.168;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@crowdculture.eu designates 69.194.224.168 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=user@crowdculture.eu
Received: from crowdculture.eu (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by crowdculture.eu (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.2ubuntu1) with ESMTP id q569LFcH003157
    for <janis.kesteris3@gmail.com>; Wed, 6 Jun 2012 09:21:15 GMT
Received: (from user@localhost)
    by crowdculture.eu (8.14.3/8.14.3/Submit) id q569LEJ9003156
    for janis.kesteris3@gmail.com; Wed, 6 Jun 2012 09:21:14 GMT
Date: Wed, 6 Jun 2012 09:21:14 GMT
From: user <user@crowdculture.eu>
Message-Id: <201206060921.q569LEJ9003156@crowdculture.eu>
Subject: test weee 111
```

Comment: Don't have an answer but a couple of comments: With subjects like "test weee 111" you are increasing your spam score. Plus your SPF record is not quite right. I suggest you remove /16 from it unless you really want to deliver mail from such a wide range

Answer (score -1):

There appears to be a man-in-the-middle that is rebuilding the packs to spoof UPS,com as the source (header indicates an IP rejection failure) then bounces the mail through senseoffashion.com (which doesn't do anything but try to get your pii. The end-product e-mail is from "UPS quantum.com" which isn't much of a social engineering trick. This email should be
easily filtered, but would make a marvelous test case for local administrators to test their user's awareness of this type of attack.

Comment: The only mention of UPS is this answer(!)